# Receiving SMS using GSM and controlling LED using Arduino

Tags: arduino, led, gsm

Has someone come up with a solution with the above stated problem?

We are using Arduino Duemilanove and SIM 900 GSM module (http://robokits.co.in/shop/index.php?main_page=product_info&products_id=303)

We've tried to work on the similar problem of lightning Leds from port 9-12 when we send an sms #aibicidi, where i = 0 or 1, 0 =off, 1=on.
Eg. #a1b1c1d1 will switch on all the Led's.

When we upload the code and run it through serial monitor and enter the #a1b1c1d1 in the serial monitor, we can see all the led's lighten up.  But if we send the sms with having content "#a1b1c1d1", we dont see any function of leds.

It would be great if anyone can give some guidance about the same.

```
 char inchar; //Will hold the incoming character from the Serial Port.


 int led1 = 9;
 int led2 = 10;
 int led3 = 11;
 int led4 = 12;

 void setup()
 {
 // prepare the digital output pins
 pinMode(led1, OUTPUT);
 pinMode(led2, OUTPUT);
 pinMode(led3, OUTPUT);
 pinMode(led4, OUTPUT);
 digitalWrite(led1, LOW);
 digitalWrite(led2, LOW);
 digitalWrite(led3, LOW);
 digitalWrite(led4, LOW);
 //Initialize GSM module serial port for communication.


 Serial.begin(9600);
 delay(3000); // give time for GSM module to register on network etc.
 Serial.println("AT+CMGF=1"); // set SMS mode to text
 delay(200);
 Serial.println("AT+CNMI=3,3,0,0"); // set module to send SMS data to serial out upon receipt 
 delay(200);
 }

 void loop() 
 {
 //If #a1b1c1d1 comes as sms, all led's should light up.
 if(Serial.available() >0)
 {
 inchar=Serial.read(); 
 if (inchar=='#')
   {
   delay(10);
   inchar=Serial.read(); 

 //first led
   if (inchar=='a')
     {
   delay(10);
   inchar=Serial.read();

 if (inchar=='0')
   {
   digitalWrite(led1, LOW);
   } 
 else if (inchar=='1')
   {
   digitalWrite(led1, HIGH);
   }
 delay(10);


 //Second led
 inchar=Serial.read(); 

 if (inchar=='b')
   {
   inchar=Serial.read();
 if (inchar=='0')
 {
 digitalWrite(led2, LOW);
 } 

 else if (inchar=='1')
 {
 digitalWrite(led2, HIGH);
 }
 delay(10);

 // Third led
 inchar=Serial.read(); 
 if (inchar=='c')
 {
 inchar=Serial.read();
 if (inchar=='0')
 {
 digitalWrite(led3, LOW);
 } 
 else if (inchar=='1')
 {
 digitalWrite(led3, HIGH);
 }
 delay(10);

 //Fourth led

 inchar=Serial.read(); 
 if (inchar=='d')
 {
 delay(10);
 inchar=Serial.read();
 if (inchar=='0')
 {
 digitalWrite(led4, LOW);
 } 
 else if (inchar=='1')
 {
 digitalWrite(led4, HIGH);
 }
 delay(10);
 }
 }
 Serial.println("AT+CMGD=1,4"); // delete all SMS
 }
 }
 }
 }
 }
```

Comment: I was able to solve the above state problem.  Get to this link, to the last post: http://www.edaboard.com/thread284929.html

Comment: You may want to put your experience down as an answer, elaborating a bit on the content of your provided link, then accept your own answer. Not a link-only answer, of course, as those add little value to this site, and become meaningless when the link target changes location or the site dies at some point.

Answer (score 1):

your code is good for serial terminal, but not for GSM modem. It always take command in form of AT use AT+CMGR=1 to read the message.... send this command to modem and see the reply....

Comment: This would retrieve 1 message, but without deleting it, the same message would remain in the queue, choking the application.

Answer (score -1):

Do the modification `AT+CNMI=2,2,0,0,0` instead of `AT+CNMI=3,3,0,0` from our previous code. Then the relay will work.

Comment: What on earth does "our previous code" refer to?

Comment: @Dave Tweed  It is a reference to an answer in a thread on the board linked to in the comment posted by OP on his own post.  Perfectly simple old chap.  LOL.